# do anyone know how to view html of a pulled github repository in codesandbox?

Tags: codesandbox

i just imported a github repository in codesandbox, it is full of html examples. and i tried to start a server to serve the html files. but the http-server do not seem to work.
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/serene-ding/svg-essentials-examples/gh-pages?file=/ch12/animate_color.html:1,1&workspaceId=e5703be0-a236-4960-bc4d-67158e4a914c

i tried to npm install http-server. it warns that command not found.
i am new to codesandbox, still trying to figure out how to make it work now.
[image]

Comment: Please include actual code and not links to code or pictures of code.  Also that link give an "Unable to access this workspace" error anyway, so just please put the code you want help with in your question.

Answer (score 0):

After importing, do below.

1. in the terminal type `npm init` and hit enter
2. just enter to select defaults ...
3. `npm i live-server'
4. create an index.js file
5. add code in index.js like below

```
      var liveServer = require("live-server");

      liveServer.start({
        file: "index.html" // change the file name if needed
       });
```

6. in terminal type `node index` and hit enter.

Thats all.